# How to fix a ZTE Score after multiple adjustments

Tags: google-play-store, partitions, zte-score

I have recently downloaded Link2SD and made another partition to get more app space and it worked. Even recently, I made a 2nd partition to see if I could create more space, but then when I rebooted, all my apps were gone (Including the Google Play Store, that's on my SD Card). So I booted back into recovery mode and then I performed a backup and restore then tried to reboot. When I tried to reboot, it stayed on the ZTE logo. Then I booted back into recovery mode once more the wipe data, cache, and Dalvik. After I deleted them, It still stayed on the ZTE logo. How do I fix my phone?

Comment: Looks like you screwed up your SDCard's partition table. If it's a removable SDCard: Have you tried bootin without it being inserted?

Comment: That didn't work, it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: Could it be you accidentally created that new partition somewhere else than on the external card, and might have screwed some internal storage? Apart from that, I'm out of ideas.